# elementary If else statement not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, var, hoisting

I am totally new to javaScript and cannot understand why this elementary if else statement won't work. And before you mark down yes I have looked and can't find a simple answer to this simple question. Many thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function (){

var try = 0;

if (try == 0){

    alert("yes");

} else {

    alert("no");

}

});
```

Comment: *The use of a keyword for an identifier is invalid*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because ***try*** is a javascript keyword and you cannot use it.

Change it to **try1** just for instance.

```js
$(document).ready(function (){

            var try1 = 0;

            if (try1 == 0){

                alert("yes");

            } else {

                alert("no");

            }

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```